# Resize image dataset from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I acquire dataset from Kaggle [Arabic Handwritten Digits Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mloey1/ahdd1) and the data have shape about (60000, 784) which is 60k image with 28x28 pixels each (training data). And then I want to combine it with other dataset that have shape (13440x1024) [Arabic Handwritten Characters Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mloey1/ahcd1) that have 13440 and 32x32 pixels (training data)

My idea is to convert that dataset (arabic digits) into image (png or jpg) to size 32x32 using PIL and store it to a folders, and then turn again all those converted image to csv file again.

My question is, is there a better and efficient way to convert it? because I think it takes a long journey...

Thank you very much!

Comment: depends what you mean 'better'. maybe convert into memory without file write and read again is faster.

Comment: thanks for the advice @LeiYang , I'll try it